# Cannot display a number as the sum of two others

Tags: python

I have a Python exercise to do but I can't figure out how to do it.

My problem is that I can not get correct display, especially on the line "New number: x+y=z".

Thank you very much and don't hesitate to tell me if I did something wrong.

The objective of the program is to test whether a positive integer greater than 10 is a lucky
number.
A lucky number is an integer which, when you add the squares of each of its digits, then the squares of the digits of that result and so on, you get the result 1.

The calculation stops when the number becomes less than 10.

```
Please enter a number greater than 10: 913
9^2=81
1^2=1
3^2=9
New number: 81+1+9=91
9^2=81
1^2=1
New number: 81+1=82
8^2=64
2^2=4
New number: 64+4=68
6^2=36
8^2=64
New number: 36+64=100
1^2=1
0^2=0
0^2=0
New number: 1+0+0=1
913 is a lucky number!
Please enter a number greater than 10: 97
9^2=81
7^2=49
New number: 81+49=130
1^2=1
3^2=9
0^2=0
New number: 1+9+0=10
97 is not a lucky number.
```

The format should be identical to the example.

This is my code :

```
nb = nb_user
while nb > 10:
    nb_list = list(str(nb))
    add = 0
    for i in nb_list:
        square = int(i) ** 2
        print(str(i) + "^2 = " + str(square))
        add = add + square
    print("New number: " + str(add))
    nb = add
```

Comment: Hi Coding, welcome to StackOverflow! I'm having some difficulty understanding your issue, what specifically is not working with your program?

Comment: Your script never checks whether the result is `1` to tell if it's a lucky number.

Comment: FYI: you don't need to convert the string to a list. If you iterate over a string, you get the characters.

Comment: First you need an additional list to store each "square" value (as string would be best here). Finally use the string method "join" to join the squares with plus signs. Then you can print this, an equal sign and the "add" value.

Comment: does the addition stop when all numbers are less than 10? Why did you stop processing 97 after the second iteration and not go with 1 + 0 = 1? Is that because you got to 1+9+0 (all single digits)?

Answer (score 0):

You want the calculation to stop when the number is less than 10. So, change your while loop from

```py
while nb > 10:
```

to

```py
while nb >= 10:
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that in each iteration, nb might have an arbitrary number of digits, you can use `join` to format the equation, which can combine a list of `str` separated by a delimiter.

For example,

```
'+'.join(['1','2','3'])
```

gives

```
'1+2+3'
```

To format the string, other than using `+`, we can use either `format` or string interpolation for readability.

```
str1 = 'value1'
str2 = 'value2'
print('{}={}'.format(str1, str2))
print(f'{str1}={str2}')
```

Outputs:

```
value1=value2
value1=value2
```

Applying these methods to your solution, the code is as follows:

```py
nb = nb_user
while nb >= 10:
    sum = 0
    squares = []
    for i in str(nb):
       square = int(i) ** 2
       print(f'{i}^2={square}')
       sum += square
       squares.append(str(square))
    print(f'New number:{"+".join(squares)}={sum}')
    nb = sum
```